# How can I compile my Java class depending on another class and a some libraries?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

My structure looks like this

```
\Project1 
  \src
    \pkg1
      Main.java
    \pkg2
      Auxillary.java
  \Destination
    \class
    \lib
```

I need to compile Main.java which has dependencies in Auxillary.java and jars in \lib into \Destination\class

I am in the Project1 directory.

I tried

```
javac -cp Destination\lib\*;src\pkg2\* -d Destination\class
```

However, I get a `package not found` for Auxillary.java.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classpath entry can't refer to a *source* directory. Try this:

```
javac -Djava.ext.dirs=Destination\lib -d Destination\class
      src\pkg1\Main.java src\pkg2\Auxiliary.java
```

i.e. compile *all* the source code in one go. Alternatively:

```
javac -Djava.ext.dirs=Destination\lib -d Destination\class
      src\pkg2\Auxiliary.java

javac -Djava.ext.dirs=Destination\lib -cp Destination\class
      -d Destination\class src\pkg1\Main.java
```

That will compile Auxiliary.java first, and then use its destination directory as part of the classpath when compiling Main.java.

Comment: Huh. *A classpath entry can't refer to a source directory.* - preferably the `-sourcepath` is used for this, but if this is not set, the classpath works just fine to find source files. I suppose in this case the problem is that kunjan did indicate the package directory instead of the root one (i.e. `src`). And of course, the `*` is also wrong there. `-cp Destination\lib\*;src` should work fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant script to make these steps simpler. Try once!